# dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: files list file for package...:Bad address

Tags: 16.04

I have encountered this problem many times, and reloading can't solve the problem. Now I can't even install and uninstall any packages, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please post the full error message. You can also try `sudo apt --fix-broken install`